# Angularjs, intellisense for setting value of directive in html5 (webstorm)

Tags: html, angularjs, webstorm, directive

Just want to ask a simple question since I am new to angularjs and html5.

I have written a directive to check if user has permission for a certain thing. Permissions are all an array of strings. Using directive I am hiding or showing a UI element if user has permission for that. For example if user doesn't have permission for editing a user, I would hide the edit button with the help of directive as follows;
div that contains edit button

```
<div has-restriction="UserEditNotAllowed"><button>Edit User</button></div>
```

My question is instead of typing in string "UserEditNotAllowed", is there a way so that while typing it, using intellisence I can see permission strings that are available to avoid typos.

I tried adding these permission string in $rootScope but intellisense doesn't show that. I am using webstorm.

Thanks,
Imad.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't have to use your own directive for hiding stuff based on app logic. Instead you could use `ng-show`.

```
<div ng-show="userAllowed"><button>Edit user</button></div>
```

Then inside your controller, set `$scope.userAllowed = true;` whenever you want the button to become visible.

As for intellisense, that is an entire other question which should be aimed at webstorm.

Comment: purpose of writing directive is to consolidate logic to verify that a user role has certain permission or not and then we would not need to define variables in controllers all over the app. With this approach I can intercept the routes as well and restrict access if user doesn't have permission. I adopted the concept presented in this article : [link](http://nadeemkhedr.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/how-to-do-authorization-and-role-based-permissions-in-angularjs/)

Comment: What I need is just a way to define the list of permissions in such a way that when I set a value for a directive in html, the value completes itself (i.e., it behaves as object instead of string. something like how databound objects in xaml auto complete itself) and is global so that its accessible in all html pages. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the way authorization is done in the post you linked to. You should look at `angular-ui-router`.

Comment: Thanks MWay for refering to ui-router. How safe would it be to use it since as mentioned on their github page, its under active development and APIs are subject to change?

Comment: All depends on what you are working on I suppose. I use it currently, with little issues, but I'm not building life or death mission critical software so...